# Create a new list of objects containing items with the most recent date

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a list `ListA` comprising a Collection of objects from a single class. This class consists of three properties all of which are strings:

```
Code, Ref, StartDate
```

I want to create `ListB` ensuring only the most recent start date is selected from `ListA`

What is the most effective way of doing this with LINQ?

Example contents from ListA:

OA   001 01.01.2000

OA   001 02.01.2000

OA   001 01.12.2001

OB   002 01.01.2000

Expected contents in ListB:

OA   001 01.12.2001

OB   002 01.01.2000

Many Thanks

Comment: `ListA.OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDate).First();`

Comment: Haha! I've been experimenting with a similar line of code - so close!
Thanks I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: Will that list only the most recent dates for all Codes, or the most recent dates grouped by the codes.

Comment: Just the most recent one, you need to use `GroupBy` to get them per code.

Comment: GroupBy instead of First() or instead of OrderByDescending()

Comment: Something like `ListA.GroupBy(...).Select(...).ToList()`

Comment: `StartDate` is a string property and not a `DateTime`?

Comment: I am writing the contents back out as a fixed width file so need trailing spaces on the date, but before then i need to use the datetime datatype to carry out date queries.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
var ListA = new List<Your_Class>() { 
         new Your_Class{ Code = "OA", Ref ="001",StartDate=Convert.ToDateTime ("01.01.2000")},
         new Your_Class{ Code = "OA", Ref ="001",StartDate=Convert.ToDateTime("01.01.2000")},
         new Your_Class{ Code = "OA", Ref ="001",StartDate=Convert.ToDateTime("12.01.2001")},
         new Your_Class{ Code = "OB", Ref ="002",StartDate=Convert.ToDateTime("01.01.2000")}
};

var ListB =  from c in ListA
             group c by c.Code into grp
             select grp.OrderByDescending(c => c.StartDate).FirstOrDefault();
foreach(Your_Class your_cls in ListB) {
          Console.WriteLine(your_cls.Code+" "+your_cls.Ref+" "+ your_cls.StartDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"));
}
```

> [C# Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YLRgkx)